# Three.js animating shader uniforms doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, three.js

In all my projects, setting my shaders uniform values manually does the job and upon refreshing my page I get exactly what I expect. However, the values dont update when I try to animate them.

```
   var uniforms = { 
      size: {type: "f", value: 0.0}
   }

    var animate = function () {
        uniforms.size.value += 0.01;
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
    };

render();
```

As you can see, this is standard procedure and yet it doesnt work. I tried:

```
uniforms.size.needsUpdate = true;
```

and even tried setting needsUpdate to true for my material:

```
material.needsUpdate = true;
```

Wy wont my uniforms animate?

Comment: what is your shader where you use it?

Comment: Where are you calling `renderer.render(scene, camera);` ? [HERE](http://blog.2pha.com/demos/threejs/shaders/matrix.html) is a simple example of an animating shader.

Comment: try accessing uniforms through the material. material.uniforms.size.value += 0.1;